# Git push error RPC failed; curl 55 sslwrite() returned syscall, errno = 10053

Tags: git

I'm just trying to push to a new project via PowerShell.
    [Error messages](https://pastebin.com/kGJ0kEaR)

```
.
```

I went through this website's explanation of the errors https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/error-rpc-failed-result-55-http-code-0-301663267.html but it hasn't helped much, I've tried turning my systems firewall off, which didn't help. I believe that I might have a firewall on the flat's Internet.